# MySQL Scheduled Event Not Firing

Tags: mysql

I have so far been unsuccessful in getting any Scheduled Events to fire.

- MySQL 5.7.14
- Global variable event_scheduler is ON
- Processlist shows event_scheduler with a status of "Waiting on empty queue"
- This is a Master Server with server_id=2 and is replicated to Slaves.

The following query is used to create a scheduled event to clear out the sessions table (this is verbatim). The query itself works.

```
CREATE EVENT cleanup_session_data
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DISABLE ON SLAVE
DO
DELETE FROM session_data WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

However the Scheduled event simply does not fire.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was to remove the

```
DISABLE ON SLAVE
```

Either it is my own misunderstanding or this does not work as expected. By not including the the EVENT status is "ENABLED" whereas with it included it is "SLAVESIDE_DISABLED"

The EVENTS now fire as expected. They are also not replicated to the SLAVE.

Comment: This made my day! Thanx!

Comment: I needed to substitute `DISABLE ON SLAVE` to `ENABLE`, because my database (mariadb) by default adds `DISABLE ON SLAVE`  when anything about this is stated.